# MVC 3 Windows Authentication and Additional User Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, windows-authentication

I am new to MVC3. I am seeking for suggestions to achieve below:

1. My MVC3 Site is enabled for Windows Authentication.
2. I have separate UserProfile table in the Oracle DB which will contain roles
   information.
3. The user can have multiple products associated. For each product role(s) for user vary.

Need:

1. As soon as user is authenticated, I want to fetch the application
   specific details from DB for currently selected product. I can do
   this by RoleProvider I guess.
2. I want append this information to User object. How do I do this?
3. If the user changes the product, I should be able reset the additional information to the User object. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thanks
Arun

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Custom Principal and identity to attach additional data to your user. With a custom membership provider you can load the data from the database on authentication. 
When to product changes you can fetch the user from the current thread and you can call for example the method `User.UpdateProducts()` that you have written on the custom identity.

Here is an [Example](http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0)

[Full blown example in VB](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-vb)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is helped me to resolve my problem. I ended up mixing FormsAuthenticationTicket along with WindowsAuthenticatioin.

Answer (score 5):

I am just posting the code which I have tried. This is just an approach which I have taken. But I need epxperts comments to say whether this is good idea or not with respect to Security, Performance etc.

Step 1: Defined Custom Interface which inherits IPrincipal

```
public interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        string[] Roles { get; set; }
        string Country { get; set; }
        string Region { get; set; }
        string Department { get; set; }
        string CurrentProductId { get; set; }
        bool HasAcceptedTerms { get; set; }
    }
```

Step 2: Implement Custom Principal using above Interface

```
public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
    {
        private IPrincipal principal;

        public CustomPrincipal(IPrincipal principal, WindowsIdentity identity)
        {
            this.Identity = identity;
            this.principal = principal;
        }

        #region IPrincipal Members

        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return (principal.IsInRole(role));
        }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string[] Roles { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Region { get; set; }

        public string CurrentProductId { get; set; }

        public bool HasAcceptedTerms { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

Step 3: Define your own Role Provider. Also make an web.config entry for this provider and set this as default provider

```
public class MyCustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        List<string> _roles = new List<string> { "System Administrators", "Product Administrators", "Users", "Guests" };

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {

            //TODO: Get the roles from DB/Any other repository and add it to the list and return as array
            return _roles.ToArray();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            if (_roles.Contains(roleName))
            {
                //this.Department = "My Department";
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }


        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Step 4: Implemented below events

Note: I am serialzing additional user information into FormsAuthenticationTicket. My website is enabled for Windows Authentication.

```
protected void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object source, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null == Request.Cookies.Get("authCookie"))
            {
                var userId = e.Identity.Name;
                //TODO: You may need to get the user details like country, region etc. from DB. For simplicity, I have just assigned user roles (multiple) property

                //Instead of string array, you should use your own Class to hold this custom data and then serialize
                string[] userRoles = new string[] { "System Administrators", "Users" };

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
                xs.Serialize(writer, userRoles);

                FormsAuthenticationTicket formsAuthTicket =
                    new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                1,
                                userId,
                                DateTime.Now,
                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                                false,
                                writer.ToString());

                var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(formsAuthTicket);

                HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie("authCookie", encryptedTicket);

                Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
            }
        }
```

Step 5: Use PostAuthenticateRequest event to wrap your RolePrincipal with your CustomPrincipal. This is necessary to hold your data in Principal object so that you can access this in any part of your application. DO NOT USE Application_AuthenticateRequest TO WRAP THE WINDOWS PRINCIPAL OBJECT. IF YOU ENABLE ROLE PROVIDER, ASP.NET WILL ACTUALLY REPLACE THE WINDOWS PRINCIPAL WITH ROLE PRINCIPAL.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies.Get("authCookie");
            FormsAuthenticationTicket formsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(User, (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity);

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(formsAuthenticationTicket.UserData);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));

            object ret = xs.Deserialize(sr);
            newUser.Roles = (string[]) ret;
            Context.User = newUser;
        }
```

As suggested by Preben, I would update the cookie whenever the user swicthes to different produt.

Hope this helps for someone who is willing to store additional User Data in conjuction with Windows Authentication.

Please let me know if there is better approach to achieve the goal.